# Почему textview равен нулю?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Есть прием данных в текст вью,данные видно в приложении. Но когда хочу провести сравнение в лог показывает что текст вью остался равен нулю который я написал в xml.тоесть визуально меняется,данные видны но с ними ничего не могу сделать

Код получения и сравнения

```
docart.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(Productid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists() && snapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
  textValue.setText(snapshot.child("TovarValue").getValue().toString());
  priem=snapshot.child("TovarValue").getValue().toString();
            String s="0";
            int n1=Integer.parseInt(snapshot.child("TovarValue").getValue().toString());
            int n2=Integer.parseInt(s);
            if (n1==n2){
                deletedocart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pluscarzin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                plusdocart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
```

Как это выглядит в лог
[image: логд]

Comment: Что-то я не наблюдаю в вашем коде вывод в лог, что и как вы туда пишете - никому кроме вас неизвестно. И как вам ответить что вы делаете неправильно, если мы не знаем что вы там делаете?

Comment: Если надо сравнить n1 и n2 как строки, то: `n1.equals(n2)` это даст `True` или `False`  в зависимости от того, равны ли строки.